# How to determine if a range of cells contain consecutive numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am using `Excel 2016` and I am looking for the formula to determine whether the numbers in a range of cells contain at least 2 consecutive numbers.

Assuming, the range of numbers is between `D1` and `I1` (6 numbers), what would be the formula in cell `J1` to output "Y" (if cells `D1` to `I1` contain a consecutive number), else to output "N"?

Comment: Is this another lottery question?

Comment: No, it's an Excel formula question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`=IF(AGGREGATE(14,6,--(E1:H1-D1:G1=1),1)=1,"Y","N")`

Answer (score 0):

Below formula compares each cell with its adjacent cell plus one. If any of the condition is true it returns "Y" else "N".

`=IF(OR(I1=H1+1,H1=G1+1,G1=F1+1,F1=E1+1,E1=D1+1),"Y","N")`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(E1:H1-D1:G1=1),E1:H1),"Y","N")
```

It will fail if the consecutive numbers were -1 and 0. Let me know if this might pose a problem and I should find a cure for it.
Here is the formula with the cure implemented.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(E1:H1-D1:G1=1),COLUMN(E1:H1)),"Y","N")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't assume that the numbers were pre-sorted, could use:

```
=IF(SUM(--(D2:I2=TRANSPOSE(D2:I2)+1)),"Y","N")
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

This creates a 2D array in which each number in the range is compared against each number in the range +1.