# Find x consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array of non-ordered integers, and I am trying to return a TRUE or FALSE based on if x consecutive numbers can be found within the array

Example array in A1:A8 [20,17,13,16,21,22,19,18]

In B1 is [5], requiring the function to find 5 consecutive numbers.

No VBAs please

Based on similar queries and answers on this website, the best I came up with was
=AND(IF(SUM(--(A1:A8=TRANSPOSE(A1:A8)+1)),TRUE,FALSE),IF(SUM(--(A1:A8=TRANSPOSE(A1:A8)+2)),TRUE,FALSE),IF(SUM(--(A1:A8=TRANSPOSE(A1:A8)+3)),TRUE,FALSE),IF(SUM(--(A1:A8=TRANSPOSE(A1:A8)+4)),TRUE,FALSE))

I tried to mimic one of the answers from below
[How to determine if a range of cells contain consecutive numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051141/how-to-determine-if-a-range-of-cells-contain-consecutive-numbers/54052334#54052334)

Comment: Please include your attempt to make this on-topic

Comment: Can the array contain duplicates?

Comment: Consecutive is defined as increasing or decreasing consecutive integers? In the example given, I would say the result would be false. In any case, it doesn't appear that you have tried anything, right? You're just looking for someone to do this for you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, the array can contain duplicates, and consecutive is defined as any series of five consecutive integers, ascending or descending isn’t relevant. My best attempt seeks to find any number, and see if there is another number +1 in the array, all the way to +4

Answer (score 0):

`=LET(ζ,UNIQUE(A1:A8),ISNUMBER(FIND(REPT(1,B1-1),CONCAT(N(MMULT(LARGE(ζ,SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ)-1)+{0,1}),{1;-1})=1)))))`

If you're not using an English-language version of Excel then the separators within the two array constants, i.e.

`{0,1}` and `{1;-1}`

may require amendment.

This issue can be circumvented - albeit at the cost of formula brevity - with the following locale-independent version:

`=LET(ζ,UNIQUE(A1:A8),ISNUMBER(FIND(REPT(1,B1-1),CONCAT(N(MMULT(LARGE(ζ,SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ)-1)+SEQUENCE(,2,0)),SEQUENCE(2,,1,-2))=1)))))`

As per some of the solutions in the link you posted, a more concise solution will almost certainly be available if we employ a pair of offset ranges (for example, `A1:A7` and `A2:A8`), though personally I try to avoid such referencing (imagine replacing the range `A1:A8` with a Structured Table column reference, for example - generating the equivalents of `A1:A7` and `A2:A8` would then be cumbersome).